# jenkins groovy logical if conditions validity

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I added this below "if" condition in the jenkins groovy script

```
if ((sign_check == true)  &&  ((name == "abc") ||  (name == "def"))){
println "hello - yes"
}
```

And even tried using below

```
if (name == "abc" ||  name == "def"){
 if (sign_check == true) {
  println "hello - yes"
 }
}
```

When the script is triggered with "sign_check=false" and "name="def", this if condition is supposed not to trigger "hello - yes",yet in my case, it is still happening to  trigger "hello - yes".

Please advise what exactly an issue with the if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be is `sign_check`  variable is not assigned as a boolean.
Below are some tests:
**Test1** : **Gives correct results**. 
It **does not** print "hello -yes"

```
script{
       def sign_check = false
       def name ="abc"
                
      if (name == "abc" ||  name == "def"){
      if (sign_check == true) {
          println "hello - yes"
         }
     }
}
```

**Test1** : **Gives correct results**. 
It **does not** print "hello -yes"

```
script{
       def sign_check = false
       def name ="abc"
                
      if (name == "abc" ||  name == "def"){
      if (sign_check == true) {
          println "hello - yes"
         }
     }
}
```

If you are using paramterised options then you should select variable `sign_check` as boolean and not string:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters
    {
    
        booleanParam(defaultValue: true, description: '', name: 'sign_check')
        string(name: 'name', defaultValue: "abc", description: 'What is name?')
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script{
                    
                    if (params.name == "abc" ||  params.name == "def"){
                     if (params.sign_check == true) {
                      println "hello - param yes"
                     }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above gives expected results.

Comment: Yes it works - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In "Declarative syntax", other way is to use "when" condition

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters
  {
    booleanParam defaultValue: true, description: '', name: 'SIGN_CHECK'
    choice choices: ['abc', 'def'], description: 'What is name?', name: 'NAME'
  }

  stages {
    stage('Hello') {
      when {
        expression {return params.SIGN_CHECK == true}
        anyOf{
            expression { return params.NAME == 'abc'}
            expression { return params.NAME == 'def'}
        }
      }
      steps { println "hello - yes" }
    }
  }
}
```

Prints hello - yes